# express api получить URL сайта

Tags: node.js, api, express

Добрый день,
подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить URL сайта, который отправил request на api (или на какой URL будет отправлен response)

Comment: Надёжно -- никак. А вам зачем? Возможно, есть способ решить вашу проблему проще.

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, проще решить легко... хотелось изящней))

Comment: Изящней, может быть, тоже. Но если это популярная задача, думать, что есть что-то изящнее устоявшегося решения, весьма самонадеянно. Хотя и не факт, что это плохо.